# Problems calling a variadic Java function from Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, java-7

I'm having a play with the Java NIO.2 API from JDK 7.

In particular, I want to call the method: `Paths#get(String first, String... more)`

This is a static method which takes in at least one string, and returns a Path object corresponding to it. There's an overloaded form: `Paths#get(URI uri)`

However, I can't seem to call the top method from Clojure. The nearest I can seem to get is this:

```
(Paths/get ^String dir-fq (object-array 0))
```

which fails with:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

as you might expect. After all, we're passing in an Object[] to something that's expecting String[].

I've tried removing the (object-array) form - but that just causes Clojure to try to call the get(URI) method - both with and without the type hint.

Passing nil as the second argument to Paths#get(String, String...) causes the right method to be called, but Java 7 then fails with an NPE.

I can't seem to find a way in Clojure to express the type String[] - I'm guessing I either need to do that or provide a hint to the dispatch system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you noticed, it doesn't want an Object[], it wants a String[]. `object-array` does exactly what it says: it makes an array of objects. If you want to create an array with some different type, `make-array` and `into-array` are your friends. For example here:

```
(Paths/get "foo" (into-array String ["bar" "baz"]))
```

The `String` specifier there is optional in this case: if you leave out the array's desired type, Clojure uses the type of the first object as the array's component type.

Comment: Cool. Any idea why just passing a single String parameter causes the runtime to attempt to call the Paths#get(URI) method and coerce the String into a URI?

Comment: If there's only one one-argument `get` method, this wouldn't surprise me. At the bytecode level, as I think you're aware, the vararg version is just a two-arg version taking String, String[]. If you only pass one object, the compiler might say "well there's only one one-arg version, so I'll call that and hope for the best instead of wasting time on reflection to see if it matches".